# Posting to form, saying user isn't logged in, session cookie exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a form, that when submitted, it calls a jquery .ajax request like:

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: "/posts/" + id + "/add_comment",
 ..
 ..
});
```

This website has subdomains, and the session cookie after logging in looks like:

```
name: __webt_session
value: ...
host: testsubdomain.lvh.me
path: /
Secure: No
Expires: At end of session
```

Now when I submit a comment, it doesn't save the comment, it rather redirects to the login page (the html is for the login page, it doesnt' actaully redirect b/c it was an ajax call behind the scenes).

Does my url for the form action have to include the subdomain?

BTW, why does it say 'secure: NO'

**UPDATE**

I set the post url to include the full url w/subdomain, and it is still redirecting to the login page.  **Why isn't it picking up the cookie?**

When I am on the page that I am posting the form, I am logged in just fine.  The url has teh subdomain in it.  It must be that when I post to the page, for some reason or another, it thinks I am not logged in and redirects me (you have to be logged in to post a comment).  Very confused why it is not picking up the cookie.

Ideas?

Comment: If a cookie is set to "secure", than it will be transferred only over HTTPS (not over HTTP)

Comment: Which authentication library are you using? Which version of that library and rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your post has the rails `authenticity_token` if your controller's action has `protect_from_forgery`

In rails 3.0.x (x > 3) if `verify_authenticity_token` fails, it logs you out, so your authentication will fail.

**UPDATE**

To do this in your javascript post, you'll want to add a post parameter called `authenticity_token`. The value of this parameter can be determined in two ways:

1) In your controller call `form_authenticity_token` and pass this value to the javascript.

2) In your layout, add this line

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

This will add the following to the head of your document

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Sm8z1XLTzI5HCy7+MIB+yFXiGUdS1byUHI8brHknirY="/>
```

You can retrive the post value with a little javascript like this:

```
document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content
```

In this version, you can be uber correct and use the value of

```
document.getElementsByName('csrf-param')[0].content
```

to determine the name of the post parameter

Comment: ah, thanks I hope this is it! Since this is a ajax call, I have to manually add this in my .js file somehow, and then pass it as a parameter to the .ajax call right?

Comment: how can I access the token from within a controller?

Comment: What should the post key be fore the token?  the snippet of the .js seems to be modifying something else that is built-in rails, mine is custom.

Comment: Fair questions! I have revised my answer.

Comment: Did that take care of the problem?